# How to use php pages in templateurl in stateprovider of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes, state

I used the stateprovider with an html page.

```
$stateProvider
.state('about', {
url: '/about',
templateUrl: 'pages/about.html
});
```

But i changed the about file to about.php and also in the code below.

```
$stateProvider
.state('about', {
url: '/about',
templateUrl: 'pages/about.php
});
```

It still seems to link to about.html somehow, because if I delete the about.html and keep about.php it is not working

Im wondering how I can use the .php file extention in the stateprovider.

EDIT:

Okay so this does work on my personal hosting space but not on external hosting on one.com. Any idea how to fix this?